# Create element, and add parent attributes to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a button that opens a modal for editing a document. I add attributes to the button and grab them when the button is clicked. I've added an icon to the innerHTML of my button, but that doesn't inherit the attributes (ie if the icon within the button is clicked, the modal doesn't have the data, while clicking outside the icon but still inside the button works fine).

```
const edit = document.createElement('button')
edit.innerHTML = '<svg class="review__icon"><use xlink:href="/img/icons.svg#icon-edit"></use></svg>'

edit.setAttribute('data-key', el._id)
edit.setAttribute('data-title', el.title)
...
```

Now obviously I could just add the same attributes to the icon, but that seems daft. Is there some way to have the icon in my innerHTML inherit the data-attributes of its parent, the button?

Comment: Can you show where the listener is attached? Are you attaching it to the `edit` variable?

Comment: Yes, there is a click listener on the edit button/variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the icon within the button is clicked, the modal doesn't have
>   the data, while clicking outside the icon but still inside the button
>   works fine.

The solution is to apply to the icon the CSS style:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

While maintaining the icon's visibility, this effectively makes the icon insubstantial.

When you try to click the icon, you will click *right through it* and click on the button underneath instead.

---

**Further Reading:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeating the attributes again, or setting attributes at all, how about simply referencing the `el` in the listener?

```
const edit = document.createElement('button')
edit.innerHTML = '<svg class="review__icon"><use xlink:href="/img/icons.svg#icon-edit"></use></svg>'
edit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(el._id);
  console.log(el.title);
});
```

(if this is inside a loop, make sure `el` is declared with `const` or `let`)